# Is there any way to put backend-handler on the button in HTML except <form> and XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Suppose I have an html page with a button. And I have an app on the server-side which accepts HTTP POST reqests. I know 2 ways to force a browser to generate request:

1. HTML form element `<form method="POST"..> </form>`
2. Ajax: `XMLHttpRequest`

Is there any other ways?

Comment: No, they are the only two ways of making a POST request.

Comment: You can as well dynamically add `script` or `iframe` with parameters in their `src` attribute and then process content. Server side must serve GET requests.